# How to add XP points to Google Play Games?

Tags: android, google-play-services, achievements

I added two achievements for test purposes.I have a Long variable whose name is longScore1.I can save the score, but the user does not gain XP.My goal is to give users XP.
Here my codes;

```
  GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(MainActivity.this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
        gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.container_pop_up));

        Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .unlock(getString(R.string.achievement_paaaa));

        longScore1+=80;
```

Answer (score 0):

XP Points are handled as "Achievements", and Achievement has to be registered to the google play console.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#creating_an_achievement

Please refer to this API document

Comment: i know this document.after i read this document already i added two achievements.I don't know if there is an error in the code section. Thank you for your help.